# I think render works twice

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm only learning React, trying to write a simple TODO list app. When I'm trying to add a new task, two identical tasks are added. I tried to debug by the console.log element and saw a problem. render works twice, so my button sends info to the function twice. Can someone please guide me to the solution? Here is the code.

```
    import React from 'react';

    class TaskInput extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          input: ''
        };
      }

      addTask = () => {
        const { input } = this.state;
        if (input) {
          this.props.addTask(input);
          this.setState({ input: '' });
        }
      };

      handleEnter = event => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') this.addTask();
      };

      inputChange = event => {
        this.setState({ input: event.target.value });

      };

      render() {
        const { input } = this.state;
        console.log(this.state); 
        return (
          <div className="task-input">
            <input
              type="text"
              onKeyPress={this.handleEnter}
              onChange={this.inputChange}
              value={input}
            ></input>
            <button onClick={this.addTask } >ADD</button>

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default TaskInput;
```

Here is the App.js code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Task from './components/Task';
    import TaskInput from './components/TaskInput';

    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor () {
        super();

        this.state = {
          tasks: [
            {id: 0, title: 'Create Todo-app', done: false},
            {id: 1, title: 'Do smth else', done: true},
            {id: 2, title: 'Do more things', done: false}
          ]
        };
      }

    addTask = task => {
      this.setState(state => {
        let {tasks} = state;
        console.log("state");
        tasks.push({
          id: tasks.length !==0 ? tasks.length : 0,
          title: task,
          done: false
        });
        return tasks;
      });
    }

    doneTask = id => {
      const index = this.state.tasks.map(task => task.id).indexOf(id);
      this.setState(state => {
        let {tasks} = state;
        tasks[index].done = true;
        return tasks;
      });
    };
    deleteTask = id => {
      const index = this.state.tasks.map(task => task.id).indexOf(id);
      this.setState(state => {
        let {tasks} = state;
        delete tasks[index];
        return tasks;
      })
    };
    render() {

      const { tasks } = this.state;
      const activeTasks = tasks.filter(task => !task.done);
      const doneTasks = tasks.filter(task => task.done)

       return (
       <div className = "App">
         <h1 className="top">Active tasks: {activeTasks.length}</h1>
         {[...activeTasks, ...doneTasks].map(task => (
          <Task
            doneTask={() => this.doneTask(task.id)}
            deleteTask={() => this.deleteTask(task.id)}
            task={task}
            key={task.id}
             ></Task>))}
             <TaskInput addTask={this.addTask}></TaskInput>
       </div>
       );
      }
    }
    export default App;
```

Comment: I think you need to check your keyCode if its for enter only then you should call the addTask

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to make calls to addTask() twice. Could you please post where you are rendering this todo list?

Comment: Okay, I'll update with the App.js code in a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are accidentally directly modifying the state inside `addTask`.

The line `let {tasks} = state;` is creating a reference to the original state, rather than a new copy, and then your push modifies the state directly.

Using [expansion/spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get a copy of your array like this should work:

```
addTask = task => {
  this.setState(state => {
    const tasks = [ ...state.tasks ];
    tasks.push({
      id: tasks.length !==0 ? tasks.length : 0,
      title: task,
      done: false
    });
    return { tasks };
  });
}
```

Using `let tasks = [ ...state.tasks ];` will create a new array rather than a reference, and prevent the state from being modified directly.

The reason you were seeing double results was that you effectively set the state with the push, and then set it again with the returned value.

Comment: `deleteTask` has the same problem, btw `let tasks = ` can actually be a `const tasks` and you don't need `...state` in the returned object. It can be just `{ tasks }`.

Comment: Really sorry, my fault, this really works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a little bit. It's working here. Would you please check?

```js
class TaskInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      input: "",
      tasks: []
    };
  }

  addTask = newTask => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      input: "",
      tasks: [...state.tasks, newTask]
    }));
  };

  handleEnter = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") this.addTask(event.target.value);
  };

  inputChange = event => {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { input } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="task-input">
        <input
          onKeyPress={this.handleEnter}
          onChange={this.inputChange}
          value={input}
        ></input>
        <button onClick={this.addTask}>ADD</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TaskInput/>, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work. I've tried to implement your solution, but nothing happens, I need to change an array in App.js.